# What's the best way to keep two very similar Vue projects in sync with Git?

Tags: git, vue.js

We have one Vue project that is currently live but would like to make an "administration" version of the same application. In general, the application allows users to register, log in, and add data to their profile. We want to create a replica of the application to allow administrators to log in and make changes on behalf of end-users. For the most part, the majority of the codebase will remain the same with some tweaks to logic and UI geared towards administrators.

What would be the best method for keeping the code up-to-date in the Administration version if the "source" repo gets updated? So essentially keeping things in sync with similar files but still be able to alter files if we need to. We looked into just creating a separate branch for the Administrative version and also submodules, but not sure if either route is the correct solution.

Comment: fork maybe? https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo

Comment: Branching sounds like the thing to do.... you might also work with a single branch and using flags (controlled from a properties file, for example) to control what will be used and what will be skipped.

Comment: All common code can be extracted to a package that afterwards you can use in both projects.

Comment: @eftshift0 so by branching, would we just create two separate releases for the two separate applications then?